# Can NodeJS streams queue objects, when no downstream pipe is attached?

Tags: node.js, typescript, stream

Can nodejs streams natively queue objects, if they are not yet piped to a Writable stream?

Part 2: I can no longer process items once `super.push(null)` has been called. Can I restart a stream once `super.push(null)` has been called?

I've implemented the desired behaviour in the `Readable` queue below - it stores events until the output is piped to a stream. It does what I want, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel.

```
import { Readable, ReadableOptions } from 'node:stream'

export class OrderedQueue<EventType = unknown> extends Readable {
  // stores a queue of events
  queue: EventType[] = []

  constructor(opts?: ReadableOptions) {
    super({ objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 1024, ...opts })
  }

  add(event: EventType): boolean {
    this.queue.push(event)
    return this.queue.length <= this.readableHighWaterMark
  }

  _read(size: number): void {
    super.push(this.queue.shift() || null)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the typical use case for streams. Streams are intended for _byte streams_, such as reading from and writing to files or TCP network connections. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @rveerd - I'm using this stream in object mode - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#object-mode . I would like to know if streams natively queue chunks, if there is no downstream Writable stream.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first part of the question, but for those who want to keep writing data after the queue has been emptied, you will need to call `super.push()` (e.g. in the `add()` function), to start the stream going again.

> Once the readable._read() method has been called, it will not be called again until more data is pushed through the readable.push() method.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1

i.e.

```js
import { Readable, ReadableOptions } from 'node:stream'

/**
 * Readable stream backed by a Queue.
 */
export class OrderedQueue<EventType = unknown> extends Readable {
  // stores a queue of events
  queue: EventType[] = []

  constructor(opts?: ReadableOptions) {
    super({ objectMode: true, highWaterMark: 1024, emitClose: false, ...opts })
  }

  add(event: EventType): boolean {
    // if queue is empty, and we can't push an event downstream, then queue the event
    if (this.queue.length === 0 && !super.push(event)) this.queue.push(event)
    return this.queue.length <= this.readableHighWaterMark
  }

  waitUntilDrained(): Promise<void> {
    return this.queue.length === 0 ? Promise.resolve() : new Promise((resolve) => this.once('idle', resolve))
  }

  _read(size: number): void {
    while (this.queue.length > 0 && super.push(this.queue[0])) this.queue.shift()
    // else we received back pressure... wait until _read is called again

    // if queue is now empty...
    if (this.queue.length === 0) this.emit('idle')
  }
}
```

Rather than a `push` based model such as this, a better design would be to `pull` the data (preferably only the required data) from the Event generator.